VisualStudio C# で File.Copy でコピー後にオリジナルファイルを変更すると、コピーファイルも変更する
VisualStudio2022 C# を使って、画像のリサイズ処理を行っています。
オリジナルファイルを 別フォルダーにコピーをしてから、リサイズを実行します。
すると、

リサイズしたファイと同じサイズに、コピーしたファイルが変わってしまいます。

この原因が全く理解できず、解決できずに困っています。
何故、コピーしたファイルまで影響を受けるのか、対策も教えていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。
    private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // ファイルが使用可能になるまで待機
        WaitForFile(e.FullPath);

        // 監視フォルダ内にオリジナルを保存するフォルダのパスを作成
        string originalDirPath = Path.Combine(watcher.Path, OriginalDirName);

        // オリジナルを保存するフォルダが存在しない場合は作成
        if (!Directory.Exists(originalDirPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(originalDirPath);
        }

        // オリジナルファイルの保存先パス
        string originalFilePath = Path.Combine(originalDirPath, Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath));

        // オリジナルファイルを保存
        File.Copy(e.FullPath, originalFilePath, true);

        // リサイズが必要かどうかを判断し、必要ならリサイズ
        ResizeIfNeeded(e.FullPath);
    }

    private void ResizeIfNeeded(string filePath)
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
        {
            if (image.Width > MaxWidth || image.Height > MaxHeight)
            {
                ResizeImage(filePath, image);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResizeImage(string filePath, Image originalImage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"New file created: {filePath}");

        double ratioX = (double)MaxWidth / originalImage.Width;
        double ratioY = (double)MaxHeight / originalImage.Height;
        double ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

        int newWidth = 100;/// (int)(originalImage.Width * ratio);
        int newHeight = (int)(originalImage.Height * ratio);

        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            }

            originalImage.Dispose(); // 元の画像を解放
            File.Delete(filePath); // 元のファイルを削除
            newImage.Save(filePath); // リサイズした画像を保存
        }
    }


FileSystemWatcher.Createdイベントを使っているのだと思いますが、その旨を質問文に記載してください。また、ターゲット環境および実行環境の.NET Frameworkあるいは.NETのバージョンや、OSのバージョンも記載してください。

File.Delete()でファイルを削除した後、Bitmap.Save()で保存すると、同名のファイルを新規作成したことになります。
これによってFileSystemWatcher.Createdイベントが再度発生しますが、そのときリサイズ済みの画像のWidthまたはHeightが再び条件に引っかかってリサイズ処理が走っているFile.Copy()が再実行されているのでは？
まず保存直前のFile.Delete()が無駄で、普通にBitmap.Save()で上書き保存すればよいはず。また、そもそもMath.Min()で縦横の縮小率のうち小さいほうを選んでいるので、リサイズ後のWidthまたはHeightのどちらかがまだ条件に引っかかることがありえるはず。
たとえバックアップ先ディレクトリに同名のファイルがすでに存在していても、File.Copy()の第3引数bool overwriteにtrueを指定して無条件に上書きコピーするという設計も危険だと思います。
単にコードと結果だけをながめていても原因究明にはつながりにくいので、Debug.WriteLine()などでデバッグログを適宜出力したり、デバッガーでブレークしてステップ実行したりしながら、イベントの発生状況や途中の演算結果などがどうなっているのかを確かめるべきです（初心者の場合は特に）。

ありがとうございます。
リサイズで作成されたファイルの再処理は発生していないようです。Console.WriteLine($"New file created: {filePath}");が出力されないので。
Math.Min()に関しては、規定のサイズに収まるようにするため必要で、これによりサイズチェックで処理対象から除外されます。
File.Deleteはご指摘の通り、必要ありませんでした。

そして、最終的に「エクスプローラで見てた監視フォルダとオリジナル保存フォルダを閉じた」ところ、正常に動くようになりました。
なぜ、開いてたフォルダを閉じたら正常に動くようになったのかわかりません。他に何もしていないので…。今のところ正常に動作しているようです。このまましばらく様子を見ます。ありがとうございました。

@light 「リサイズで作成されたファイルの再処理は発生していないようです。Console.WriteLine($"New file created: {filePath}");が出力されないので。」・・・とのことですが、Console.WriteLine まで行ってないと思いますよ。私の回答を読みましたか？　(1) Created イベントが発生するとイベントハンドラの OnCreated メソッドが実行される ⇒ (2) ResizeImage メソッドが呼び出されて newImage.Save(filePath); で縮小画像を保存 ⇒ (3) 保存操作で再び Created イベントが発生する ⇒ (4) 再びそのイベントハンドラの OnCreated メソッドが実行され、その中の File.Copy(e.FullPath, originalFilePath, true); で、縮小後の FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath の画像ファイルが originalDirPath フォルダにコピー（上書き）されたのではないですか。

@light すみません、リサイズ処理まで再実行されているという予測は自分の勘違いでした。回答の一部を訂正しています。@WebSurfer さんも述べられていますが、File.Delete()でファイルを削除した後、Bitmap.Save()によってFileSystemWatcher.Createdのイベントハンドラーが2回目に実行されるとき、File.Copy()が無条件で再実行されているのが問題かと。不要なFile.Delete()を除去する前の状態のコードで、FileSystemWatcher.Createdのイベントハンドラー入口にログ出力を仕込んでみてください。

まさにご指摘のとおりでした。縮小後にOnCreatedが走り「縮小されたファイルがコピーされる」ことが原因でした。この部分修正いたします。ありがとうございました！


オリジナルファイルを 別フォルダーにコピーをしてから、リサイズを実行します。すると、リサイズしたファイと同じサイズに、コピーしたファイルが変わってしまいます。

「オリジナルファイル」というのは OnCreated メソッドの FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath で、「別フォルダ」というのは originalDirPath ですよね？
で、FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath のファイルを originalDirPath フォルダにコピーした後、FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath のファイルを縮小するというのがやりたいことですよね？
しかし、質問のコードでは originalDirPath フォルダにコピーした画像ファイルまで縮小されてしまうと言ってますか？
質問のコードは ResizeImage メソッドで FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath の画像ファイルを縮小して newImage.Save(filePath); で保存しているようですが、その際再度 OnCreated メソッドが実行されるのではないですか？　それを確認していただけますか？
そうだとすれば、再度実行された OnCreated メソッドの File.Copy(e.FullPath, originalFilePath, true); で、縮小後の FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath の画像ファイルが originalDirPath フォルダにコピー（上書き）されたのではないですか。

はい、そのとおりでした。縮小したファイルによりイベント発火して、縮小したものをコピーする状態でした。処理の順番を変えて「縮小するときのみ、コピーする」にしてみます。ありがとうございます！

@light File.Delete(filePath); を削除するだけで期待通りに動くのでは？　Visual Studio のデバッガを使って、File.Delete(filePath); がある時と、それをコメントアウトした時で、コードがどのように実行されていくかの違いを調べてください。


リサイズしたファイと同じサイズに、コピーしたファイルが変わってしまいます。

他の回答にもあるように、ResizeImage メソッドの以下のコードで、FileSystemWatcher.Created が再度発火し、リサイズされた画像が上書きコピーされてしまっているのだと思います。
newImage.Save(filePath); // リサイズした画像を保存

FileSystemWatcher.Created が発火されないようにするためには、ファイルを Stream で開いて変更を反映する必要があります。
これを行うためには、画像ファイルの変更を MemoryStream に保存しておき、その後、対象のファイルを Stream で開いて変更を反映してやります。
private void ResizeImage(string filePath, int width, int height)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(filePath))
        {
            using (var resizedImage = new Bitmap(width, height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
                {
                    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height);
                }

                resizedImage.Save(memoryStream, originalImage.RawFormat);
            }                    
        }

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            memoryStream.WriteTo(stream);
        }
    }
}

この場合、FileSystemWatcher.Created は発火せず、FileSystemWatcher.Changed が発火されます。
よって、FileSystemWatcher.Created で実装されているコピー操作が再度実行されなくなり、今回の問題は解消するのではないでしょうか？

ありがとうございます。そうですね。リサイズされた画像が上書きコピーですね。リサイズ処理部分ばかり意識していました。コードも提示いただきありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます！
